# How to efficiently store a history of worker hierarchy in RDBMS

Tags: mysql, innodb, rdbms

I am working with MySQL but if anyone knows a simple answer to this problem working with other databases I am willing to learn and listen.

I am still trying to work out proper structure of my database which requires storing a hierarchy of employees(but everyone has just 1 boss). Every time the tree changes I need to know how it looked like at every point in time since it will be used in calculations going forward.

My first intuition was to use closure table since the tree will not be very deep(max 6 depth). It would be very easy to use in every aspect where I need to query ancestors/descendants but since I also need to maintain history of this tree I am afraid that data will grow way too fast.

When we assume one small tree with 60 nodes every change to this tree would generate another insert to the history closure table with probably 200+ records (since it's not very deep it's not really n^2) and I can imagine this would grow the data very fast. The tree would not change very often but would be queried for calculations purposes(even then multiple trees like that when adding/removing/switching employees would grow quite fast).

So my question is - is this really the best way to keep a history of hierarchy data in RDBMS?

Comment: Relational databases in general are not particularly great at handling hierarchical data. Graph databases (such as neo4j) are a lot more suitable for such tasks.

Comment: There is no "best way". I depends.. For only 60 nodes I would probably use a simlple adjacency list.

Comment: I started with adjacency list but quickly realised that it is not going to work for my problem since if any employee changes the position it would be hard to save/read the history of the tree

Comment: I guess my question is what is the best way to store a history of hierarchical data

Comment: @MłodyProgramista let me repeat what Paul Spiegel wrote: `There is no "best way". It depends.`

Comment: Let's approach it from the other side -- What do the queries look like?  I'm referring to queries that need to look at the history.